# Is SQL injection more prone in plain PHP code in opposite to a PHP framework?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I'm using plain PHP code than an PHP/MVC framework.

I want to know, is plain PHP code more prone to SQL injection than using a PHP/MVC framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Maybe this could help you and understand more :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Yes, it is because most frameworks provide certain API and abstractions that take care of the proper data handling for you so you don’t have to think about it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for escaping string input parameters in a query. Use type casting to sanitize numeric parameters and whitelisting to sanitize identifiers.

A better solution would be to use prepared statements, you can do this by using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: thanks for the answer maybe i should use mysql_real_escape_string to avoid such injections

Comment: On a second glance this answer is *technically* correct. However, as it can be seen from the OP's response, it was totally misunderstood - due to flawed nature of the answer. Prepared statement should be offered as the only option, because it offer *complete* formatting

Answer (score 1):

Plain PHP isn't more vulnerable to SQL Injection, when you know how to program it. PHP MVC Frameworks are just plain PHP aswell, written by other humans like you :).

Comment: “when you know how to program it” is the crux. Unfortunately, many people don’t know.